# connection timeout to node service port

Tags: node.js, server, port, nmap

I have started node service in the port 3000 and i opened the port 3000 in the server, however i can't connect the web app. Anyone can help me, thank you!

Here is the screenshot of my port status.
[image]

When i use 
`nmap -p 3000 202.117.43.155`
It shows 
[image]

So the port 3000 is showed as status "filtered", where is the block?

Comment: are you testing form the local machine that the server running form or from a remote machine?

Comment: Proved a piece of the node server Please if possible

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i solved it by using Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

in your node app check if you are using `app.listen(PORT, IP_ADDRESS_OR_HOST )`
try to use  `app.listen(PORT)` instead`

Comment: sure, and it shouldn't be an issue using node!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by applying Nginx.

After install Nginx,

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com`

````
server {

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}```
````